# OptionValue not inserting correct option

Tags: function-construction, compile, options, optional-arguments

I am using `OptionsPattern` and `OptionValue` to define some switches for my custom function. Here is a minimal example:

```
t[vars_, expr_, 
  OptionsPattern[{ Experimental`OptimizeExpression, 
    Compile}]] :=
 (
  Compile[vars, expr, 
   CompilationOptions -> OptionValue[CompilationOptions],
   CompilationTarget -> OptionValue[CompilationTarget],
   Parallelization -> OptionValue[Parallelization],
   RuntimeAttributes -> OptionValue[RuntimeAttributes],
   RuntimeOptions -> OptionValue[RuntimeOptions]
   ]
  )
t[{x, y}, Sin[x*y]]
```

This produces the errors:

```
"Options expected (instead of \
OptionValue[{Experimental`OptimizeExpression,Compile},{},\
CompilationOptions]) beyond position 2 in \
Method->{OptionValue[{Experimental`OptimizeExpression,Compile},{},\
CompilationOptions]}. An option must be a rule or a list of rules."
```

```
"Options expected (instead of \
OptionValue[{Experimental`OptimizeExpression,Compile},{},\
RuntimeOptions]) beyond position 2 in \
Method->{OptionValue[{Experimental`OptimizeExpression,Compile},{},\
RuntimeOptions]}. An option must be a rule or a list of rules"
```

```
"OptionValue[{Experimental`OptimizeExpression,Compile},{},\
RuntimeAttributes] is not a known runtime attribute and will be \
ignored"
```

and fails to execute with default values passed to the options. OptionValue appears to fail to grab the correct value. (Moreover, `Method` appears to be being assigned a value even though `Compile` has no such option, but this could just be internal definitions to Compile)

Assigning explicitly something like

```
t[{x, y}, Sin[x*y], 
 CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True}]
```

produces similar errors. Why isn't the correct `OptionValues` being parsed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Compile` holds its arguments, and doesn't recognize the unevaluated `Rule[_, _OptionValue]` as an option.  Use `With` to inject the options into `Compile`:

```
t[vars_, expr_, OptionsPattern[{Experimental`OptimizeExpression, Compile}]] := With[
    {
        opts = {
            CompilationOptions -> OptionValue[CompilationOptions],
            CompilationTarget -> OptionValue[CompilationTarget],
            Parallelization -> OptionValue[Parallelization],
            RuntimeAttributes -> OptionValue[RuntimeAttributes],
            RuntimeOptions -> OptionValue[RuntimeOptions]
        }
    },
    Compile[vars, expr, opts]
]
```